# Proving the statement: "If R is complete and transitive, then I is an equivalence relation".

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have difficulties to prove this: "If R is complete and transitive, then I is an equivalence relation".

I do not know where to start ...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does complete mean?

Comment: Complete if ∀ x, y ∈ X, xRy V yRx

Comment: How does $I$ relate to $R$?  Without some definition you can't prove this as we know nothing  about $I$, not even that it is a relation.

Comment: No idea, the teacher just gave us this statement and asked us to prove it

Comment: Your teacher is wrong: since when is $x \le y$ (on a linearly ordered set, like $\mathbb{N}$ or the reals) an equivalence relation? It doesn't hold that $xRy$ implies $yRx$ in that case, this is not symmetrical but antisymmetrical. Or is your $I$ something derived from $R$ somehow? Like $xIy$ iff $xRy \land yRx$?

Comment: I am guessing that you're writing "complete" as a translation of something. The correct term would be "total". You also switch from $R$ to $I$. What is $I$?

Comment: When you do not know where to start from, the simplest thing is to literally write down ***all*** the definitions relevant to your question. The definition of "complete" and of transitive and of an equivalence, anything that is given with a definition. Write them as "assumptions", the things which are given and "we need to check" for things that you need to verify (e.g. the properties of an equivalence relation). Then start working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true under the following interpretation:

Let $R$ be a complete and transitive relation on a set $X$. 
Then define $$\forall x,y \in X: xIy \leftrightarrow xRy \land yRx$$

then $I$ is an equivalence relation.

Proof:

- by completeness of $R$ we have that $xRx$ must hold (either that or its reverse :) ) so $xIx$ also holds by definition.
- If $xIy$ holds we know that $xRy$ and $yRx$ both hold, and this is independent on their order ($\land$ is symmetric) so we have $yRx \land xRy$ and hence $yIx$, so $I$ is symmetric.
- Suppose $xIy, yIz$ hold. Then the first gives us $xRy$, $yRx$, the second $yRz$, $zRy$. From $xRy$, $yRz$ we conclude $xRz$ from $R$'s transitivity, and the same we do for $zRy$, $yRx$ giving us $zRx$. So we have both $xRz$ and $zRx$ hence $xIz$ and so $I$ is transitive.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I finally begin to understand the reasoning!